# Word for someone who is a good judge of character?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that can be used to describe someone who has a 'good judge of character?'

Comment: Relevant meta: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7435/13804.

Answer (score 5):

**Intuitive** and **Astute** come into mind.

***Intuitive***

> *adjective*
>
> using or based on what one feels to be true even without conscious reasoning; instinctive
>
> Tom is an intuitive person; he can tell a person's character by a mere five minute conversation.

---

***Astute***

> *adjective*
>
> having or showing an ability to accurately assess situations or people and turn this to one's advantage

However, astute might contain a negative connotation regarding using the ability to one's advantage.

Answer (score 2):

One word that could fit **perspicacious**:

> able to judge quickly and correctly **what people** and situations **are really like**

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/perspicacious))

Or **shrewd**:

> able to **judge people** and situations **very well** and to make good decisions

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shrewd))

A general word for a wise person is **sage**:

> someone who is wise and shows **good judgment**

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sage_1))

Comment: IMO, *perspicacious* nails it.

Comment: While perspicacious is good, it is a word that may not be understand by many and could sound pretentious. Depending on the audience it might not be a viable option.

Comment: @Necreaux Yes, context matters. *Perspicacious* is a pretty formal word.